# How to use Android's Sensor Batching without AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-sensors, android-wake-lock, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I want to use Androids sensor batching introduced in Android 4.4 to save some battery power. My testing device can store 184 sensor events in its fifo-queue. Using a sampling rate of 18 events/seconds I have to flush the sensor about every 10 seconds. The section on Sensor Batching in the [4.4 Documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html) proposes:

> Use that calculation to set wake alarms with AlarmManager that invoke your Service (which implements the SensorEventListener) to flush the sensor.

Since Android 5.1 the minimum wake-up-interval for the AlarmManager is 60 seconds ([see here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161244)), so this won't work? Is there an alternative for waking up the device in shorter time periods or is even better (in terms of battery efficiency) to hold a wakelock constantly? I guess the 60-seconds-constraint will have its reasons.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to receive batch data from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 60 second minimum only applies to *repeating* alarms. For one-off exact alarms, you can have much smaller delays. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) mentions this as well:

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above.

In practice, this means you'll need to schedule an exact alarm (using `setExact`), and when that alarm has fired, you'll need to take care of rescheduling it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, this is also how I ended up finally.